# Second attribute of shortcode is not changing why?

Tags: shortcode, customization

I have made a heading attribute I which my title attribute is changing but my data-a attribute is not why is it happening.

Here is the shortcode : `[test title="cus" data-a="safsaf"][/test]`

and here is the shortcode function

```
function test_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'title' => 'This is test code',
        'content' => 'content'
    ), $atts, 'test' );

    // do shortcode actions here
    $output = "<h1 title='".$atts['title']."' data-a='".$atts['content']."'>Default</h1>";
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'test','test_shortcode' );
```

but, wait when I change my `content` inside the array like this

```
$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
  'title' => 'This is test code',
  'data-a' => 'content'
), $atts, 'test' );
```

and `$output` to

```
$output = "<h1 title='".$atts['title']."' data-a='".$atts['data-a']."'>Default</h1>";
        return $output;
```

it starts working.

Comment: There's no data-a in your PHP code and you forgot to escape the attributes. Not sure h1 supports title attribute, as in best practise?

Comment: @birgire  no data-a in my PHP code. sorry can't understand